# Can't build Xamarin.iOS Binding Project with Swift framework

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin, binding

I encounter a problem building a Xamarin.iOS Binding library project.

So for context, I have to integrate a Swift framework (built with SDK `iphoneos14.5`) into a Xamarin project. The framework was delivered with Objective-C headers containing the required interface members, so I was able to use Objective Sharpie to generate the `ApiDefinitions.cs` and `StructsAndEnums.cs` files using the following command line:

```
sharpie bind -sdk iphoneos15.0 -scope MyFramework.framework/Headers/ -c -F. MyFramework.framework/Headers/MyFramework.h
```

Now, I added the generated files in a new Xamarin.iOS Bindings solution. I added the framework `MyFramework.framework` as native reference to the project, changed native reference properties to enable "Smart Link", disable "Force Load", and add UIKit and Foundation to the Frameworks entry.

The issue I'm facing is with some class types that were referenced as forward declarations in the headers of the framework, and that were ignored by Objective Sharpie. I suppose they are in the native library, but the line

```cs
using MyFramework;
```

fails and outputs `CS0246: type or namespace not found`.

How am I supposed to add this reference?

Comment: Do you have a `<FrameworkName>-Swift.h` inside `<FrameworkName>.framework/Headers/`? Did you create a binding library, as explained here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/binding-ios-swift-libraries/?

Comment: @KirilS. no, the header I have in the folder `MyFramework.framework/Headers/` is called `MyFramework.h`. I wasn't able to create a proxy framework as is suggested in the link you shared, but I was able to consume the framework in a Swift app.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'binding library', do you mean the Xamarin.iOS special library project? I did that.

Comment: You can set the library and namespace and assembly as the same name `MyFramework` , and delete the dll from main project and re-add again .